# How is it possible that the "created" timestamp for a file is later than the "last modified" one?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management, timestamp

I discovered this while looking at the file properties in File Explorer in Windows 10 for some old .wav sound files I recorded using my voice with a microphone using Audacity and never modified since.

How is it logically possible that they were "last modified" earlier than they were (allegedly) created?

It should be noted that I'm 99.99% sure that they were recorded in 2013 and not 2015. I don't understand where that 2015 timestamp comes from. Even if the file properties have got updated from me moving the files around on internal and external disks over the years, should it not be the other way around? That is, it should say that it was created in 2013 but "last modified" (for some definition of "modified") in 2015?

I don't get this at all.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you copy a file the "Creation Date" changes to the date when the file was copied. Your "original" file may be created in 2013 but since then you probably made a copy of it (in 2015) and that copy got the creation date of 2015.

Comment: While that may "explain" it, it still doesn't make any sense to me. If it can preserve the "last modified" time, why can't it also preserve the "creation" timestamp? And if this is so useful to know, why can't it have another one called "last recreated" or something?

Comment: Because the "Creation Date" is actually the date when the file "was copied", that is the date when the file "was created" (the copy), thus the creation date changes....

Comment: Some command line copy tools offer some options to not reset the "creation date" when making copies like robocopy....

Comment: Assuming that the file stays within Windows file systems. A copied file is a new file. However it still has an accurate last modified. A moved file isn't new. From other sources it depends on what info is available.